# A person that you share the neighborhood with

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word or common expression like *homie, roomie, fellow citizen* for someone who lives in your neighborhood? I think *neighbor* can be used just for those that live just next to you or next door while neighborhood could be quite big. Am I right? Is so, what's the word?

**Edit**: The reason I'm asking this is that in my native language we have a word that the rough translation of it is "same-neighbourhoodie (person)". I know it's awkward in English :). He might live a block away for example. We call people who live next door something else that I always thought it's *neighbor*.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't vote to close this as a question that can be answered with a dictionary. Most dictionaries are not clear about subtleties like what this question asks about _neighbor,_ and the question actually asks something that's hard to look up: whether there is a word that matches a specific meaning. (Theoretically a thesaurus can do that, but we all know that seldom works in practice.)

Comment: How big is "quite big"? You could say "in my area", "in my part of town", or "in my neighborhood". Can't think of a single word off-hand. *neighbor* is usually people living within a few houses of you. I would use *neighborhood*.

Comment: @user3169, Interesting, I tend to call more than that a neighborhood maybe one or two blocks around near yours but still in your walking distance. Anyway, Is there also an **informal** and **casual** way to say _neighbor_? Like _homie_. For example, you see your neighbor in the street and you say to your friend, "that's my ..."

Comment: Not specific to the fact they live nearby. You have to be a bit careful using [homie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homie) as it is a slang word, and  there is a lot of cultural influence in its use. Using it in an inappropriate setting could be problematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, I do not believe that *neighbor* strictly means people living right next to you.

> [neighbor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neighbor)
>   : a person who lives next to or near another person
>   : a person or thing that is next to or near another

This is why you might (often) hear *next-door neighbor*. Such a neighbor lives in an adjacent home to you. This is to distinguish that neighbor from a neighbor who lives in a house across from you or down the block.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. See in my language we have a different word for that. That probably made me confused and wonder. Thanks.